# Point density with ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, point, density

Now I have a lot of files that contain XY coordinates, like the picture, but this picture just contains one day. However, I want to integrate all the files I have.

[image: This is the point file that I display from CSV file]

Secondly, I want to integrate all point files. This is the main problem I have. The `"Merge"` or `"Append"` tool did not work for me at all or I did not know how to use it correctly, so I can not integrate all point files.

Actually, this is the model I would like to do but it always pops up the error. It says `"You start with the invalid character"`.

[image]

Comment: Can you please describe what error you get?

Comment: @david_p The error is "You start with the invalid character" but I fixed that problem already by using the Merge tool instead. The new problem is coming lol, How could I union or merge or integrate all the point layer I got? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your error might be related to that the feature classes names cannot start with a number. Iterations in model builder is a bit complicated and I think you need to take sub model approach or python. In your case, I would use the model builder to create event layers only and then Merge them, followed by Point Density.